# What do the shapes △ ◯ ╳ ◻ mean in Japanese? And are there variations in meaning, depending on whether or not the shape is filled?

Tags: translation, words, usage, phonetics, symbols

I am interested in Japanese culture and the symbolism used in Japan, specifically I'd like to know what the △ triangle, ◯ circle, ╳ cross and ◻ square mean to a Japanese person.

How are those shapes interpreted and do they vary depending on there being filled or not?

Comment: Related: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/169/should-we-have-a-standard-notation-for-example-sentences

Comment: This is also related http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19015/my-teacher-wrote-a-triangle-on-my-japanese-homework-what-does-it-mean

Comment: I think we could close the linked question as a duplicate of this one, since the question is wider and the existing answer here is more comprehensive and encompasses the answers on the linked question.

Comment: Let's not forget they're the Playstation symbols. Very important. Verrry important.

Answer (score 59):

- ○　まる

  - **OK; correct; yes; supported; available** (like `✔`; note that the check mark usually means "wrong" in Japanese examinations)
  - masked/censored character (like `*` in English used to mask characters in certain words; see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11810/5010))
  - rival horse; second likely to win (horse race; favorite horse is marked with `◎`)
  - win; victory; [白星](http://jisho.org/search/%E7%99%BD%E6%98%9F) (when used as opposed to 黒星 = `●` = lose)
- ×　ばつ、ぺけ、ばってん

  - **NG; wrong; no; unsupported; unavailable**
  - masked/censored character (mainly for sexual reasons; cf: [ちょめちょめ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62154/5010))
  - multiplication (math)
  - lose (game)
  - dead; extinct; obsolete (word, species, person; like `†` in English)
  - used to denote romantic relationships, especially in *yaoi* fandom (like "slash" `/` in English)
  - finished (calendar, event)
- △　さんかく

  - **partially OK; partially supported; nearly sold out; between ○ and ×; questionable**
  - second move; [後手](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%BE%8C%E6%89%8B) (in shogi, when used as opposed to `▲` = first move; sometimes inverted (`▽`))
  - negative value/earnings (finance, when positive values are marked with nothing)
  - money gain; increase (stock market, when used as opposed to `▲` = loss)
  - dark horse; third likely to win (horse race)
- □　しかく

  - unavailable character; glyph missing (see: [豆腐](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5129/5010) and [*geta* symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_typographic_symbols#Other_special_marks))
  - full-width space (as opposed to the dot `・` used to denote half-width (ascii) spaces)

And these symbols can be used as the casual placeholder for other arbitrary words/characters. (See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12907/5010))

As you can see, depending on the context, filled symbols often mean the opposite things to the unfilled ones.

Comment: × is used before the name of a dead person? Isn't that kind of harsh?

Comment: @Avery Such use is mostly limited to (semi-)academic contexts, I think. For both historical and technical reasons, the dagger sign has never been popular nor widely available in Japanese documents.

Comment: × ×  can also be read as チョメチョメ: http://zokugo-dict.com/17ti/cyomecyome.htm

Comment: +1. I just want to add (for the asker) that Japanese also use ◎ to indicate "best", "excellent", etc. or anything better than 〇. Japanese pretty much use 〇 × and △ in everyday work (I'm in the engineering consulting field) but not □ or ◎. Also, kids in kindergarten and grade school get a 花丸 (hana maru=flower circle) but not ◎ from their teachers if they get a perfect score in a test, if the teacher thinks their homework is excellent, and so on.

Comment: anecdote: Playstation has the ⭕️❌△ buttons. Sony generally requires games default to ⭕️ = select in Japan and ❌ = select outside Japan. IIRC it's now settable in the system settings where as before (PS1-PS3) it was only based on region. This means games need to display those characters dynamically like if the game says "Press ? to continue" that ? has to be updated at runtime with the correct character for the region/setting.

Comment: [These](http://conwaylife.com/wiki/User:ColorfulGalaxy/List_of_patterns_by_apgcode) [two](http://conwaylife.com/wiki/User:ColorfulGalaxy/List_of_polyominoes_by_apgcode) articles also use triangles to mean "partially OK". Was the author Japanese? I'm wondering this.

Answer (score 4):

Would just like to add that ◯ can also be used as a placeholder. For example there's a TV show called 人志松本の◯◯な話. The equivalent in English would be "Matsumoto Hitoshi's _____ story".

Answer (score 3):

◯ (まる) symbolizes “O.K., Right," Perfect," while X（ばつ）symbolizes "No," "Incorrect," and "Wrong."

The test method that requires the testees to answers in Yes (○) / No (X) format in school examinations and the written examination of driver’s license is called ”まるばつ式テスト.”

I don’t know if ◻ square and △triangle have any specific implications as a sign like ◯ and X have, except the cases of the signs being often used for the index to be placed ahead of the bullet-type sentences, like:

■Fewer people are on welfare

■But the government didn't save money

■Most families in poverty don't receive welfare.

Answer (score 0):

△　さんかく over internet could mean such thing as **san is cool/handsome people write a name and put the △ in the end bcs sankaku could be . san ga kakkee (“_**-san is cool/handsome”)with a little imagination so Name△ instead of writing it all