# How do Japanese people mark checklists?

Tags: culture

I'm wondering, how would a Japanese person fill out a Yes/No checklist?

For example, say I have a list of things to remember. I'd mark them as such:

- Get spare key  ・・・・・・・・・・・・・・ Y
- Remove items from trunk   ・・・・・ P
- Check tire pressure   ・・・・・・・・・ NA
- Call dealer  ・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・ N

Where (probably obviously) Y is yes, N is no, P is partial, and NA is not applicable.

Comment: Given that the choice is between Japanese Language on the one hand and Anime & Manga on the other (the Japanese Culture site never ended up materializing), this question is really closer to the former. I'm going to migrate this over there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When Japanese people have to distinguish *yes*, *no*, *partial* and *N/A*, they mainly use the symbols `○`, `×`, `△` and `－`, respectively.

See: [What do the shapes △ ◯ ╳ ◻ mean in Japanese? And are there variations in meaning, depending on whether or not the shape is filled?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38508/5010)

In simple ToDo lists where a user marks *done* as opposed to *undone*, a checkmark `✔` is also commonly used.