# Usage of ★●■▲◆▼ shapes in different combinations

Tags: meaning, symbols

I'm aware that "●▲■" is a [famous drawing](https://terebess.hu/zen/sengai/sengai.jpg) from a Zen Buddhist priest by the name of Gibon Sengai. This drawing can be interpreted in different ways but the most common is that the circle represents reality/mind, the triangle represents a human, and the circle the earth. Other definitions are related to design([1](https://www.ddc.co.jp/dtp/images/20181205-design-no-iroha-04-09.png),[2](https://www.ddc.co.jp/dtp/archives/20181205/140900.html)); as [placeholders](http://www.utamap.com/showkasi.php?surl=S02394)(each of the singer's names is represented by a shape). But I don't think this applies to this context. Also, the meaning of these shapes discussed [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38508/what-do-the-shapes-%E2%97%BB-mean-in-japanese-and-are-there-variations-in-meaning?rq=1) doesn't apply in this case either since there are other symbols used too (★,◆,▼).

Some examples of titles of threads from 2ch/5ch:

1. ○△□茨城のおいしいパン屋さん・４店目□△○
2. ●■▲新型インフルエンザの初期症状
3. ●■▲白山信仰を熱く語る
4. ●▲■HP公開☆Windows98SEで鯖立て☆PWS●▲■
5. ★NTT系列●▲■おまとめ請求●▲■請求一本化★
6. ■■■　 米国のエイズ感染者数は2000万人以上　■
7. ●▲■語彙は力なり その22◆▲●
8. ●▲■未だにＧショッカー＠頑張る■▲●

At first I thought the only combination being used was ●▲■, but as you can see in the examples there are different combinations like ●■▲ and ■▲●, so I guess the order is of the shapes matter.
In cases like ex 5 the ★ and ●▲■ appear to be used as brackets and the order of ●▲■ is not reversed. In other cases it's reversed like in 8. In ex 2 and 3 they don't appear to be used as brackets.

Is there any special meaning of using this characters in different combinations? (mostly in thread titles in 2ch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are just meaningless decorations used to make the title stand out. Colorful emoji was not available in 2ch yet, so they used triangles, circles, stars and squares instead.